# How to use lambda to insert a value that is two other values within the list added together

Tags: python, list

Here is my code so far:

```
# Defining the results
Results =[["Harry",20,25],["Sandra",10,12],["Michelle",23,21],["Mike",18,16]]

#Adding the two test scores and appending them onto each persons list
Results.insert(lambda [x][3],Results[x][1] + Results[x][2])

#Printing the result to check the insert worked
print(Results)
#
```

I want to combine each of the users two test results located in index 1 and 2 to create a combined result at index 3, which is at the end of each users own list.

I have tryed using the .insert() function as well as the lambda function to do this. But it says there is an error in line five (where the arrow is below) with an invalid syntax and I'm unsure how to complete this using the lambda thing. I tried using the .append() function but that did not work either.

```
                      ↓
Results.insert(lambda [x][3],result[x][1] + result[x][2])
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use a lambda at all?  Have you looked at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) for insert?

Comment: If you look at how lambdas are written in Python, using virtually any of the results found by Googling "python lambda", and compare this to how you wrote yours, the reason for the syntax error should be clearer. Of course, whether lambda is the right tool for what you're trying to do is another question entirely.

Comment: Brenarn - My teacher, who does not know how to help me, wants me to use the Lamda function instead of doing something else. That is the only reason why I am using this function, otherwise I would know how to program it.

Comment: kindall - I did Google the topic and it allowed me to improve my code to this stage, but it now comes with a different error to what it used to. :D

Comment: I just don't understand where I put the colon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend reconstructing the list, with *List Comprehension*, like this

```
>>> [result + [result[1] + result[2]] for result in Results]
[['Harry', 20, 25, 45], ['Sandra', 10, 12, 22], ['Michelle', 23, 21, 44], ['Mike', 18, 16, 34]]
```

We iterate through the `Results` list and for every individual result, we create a new result list, with the last element being the sum of second and third elements of result.

Edit: If you want to use `lambda` somehow, you can replace the list comprehension with `map` function, like this

```
>>> map(lambda result: result + [result[1] + result[2]], Results)
```

Comment: Thanks, this would be great. But I need to use the lambda function for this task. I really don't know how I can do it though.

Comment: @UrbanPretzel Please check my updated code, where I replaced the List Comprehension with the `map` function.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question as I understood it:

```
results = map(lambda x: [x[0],x[1],x[2],x[1]+x[2]], results)
```

Edited the above code to return a list of lists instead of tuples, my mistake.  This will take results [["Harry",20,25],["Sandra",10,12],["Michelle",23,21],["Mike",18,16]] and turn it into the list [['Harry', 20, 25, 45], ['Sandra', 10, 12, 22], ['Michelle', 23, 21, 44], ['Mike', 18, 16, 34]].